# Waiting for AsyncTask to complete before returning value

Tags: android

In my `PreferenceActivity` I'm implementing a `OnPreferenceChangeListener`.  In the `onPreferenceChange` function, I'm validating against a webservice before persisting the value.  I tried using `AsyncTask.get()` but it doesn't seem to be forcing the main thread to wait before returning.  Any ideas?  Will I have to validate locally?

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object value)
{
    new WebServiceCall()
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final SoapObject result)
        {
            if (result == null)
            {
                mSuccess = false;
                return;
            }

            mSuccess = true;
            setSummary(preference, value);
        }
    }.execute(activity, WEBFUNCTION, selected_ids).get();

    return mSuccess;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. An AsyncTask is *asynchronous*. And before I suggest moving the code *out* of the AsyncTask, you should never do network tasks on the main thread. What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: It has the get function that is supposed to be executed on the main thread.  The problem is that I need to validate with the webservice before persisting the value.  edit:  I can't have the `return mSuccess` happen before the AsyncTask is complete.

Comment: Persist it after onPostExecute() runs. That's what the method is there for.

Comment: This is an override of the `onPreferenceChange` function of the `OnPreferenceChangeListener`, I need to return true to tell it to persist.  I guess I might have to just always return false and manually save it myself.

Comment: Please, don't do this. Always returning false will lead to a bad user-experience. Just imagine how this would turn out. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a conceptual issue with your question. 
As far as I know, "onPreferenceChange" runs in the main thread. Any attempt to 'wait' inside this method would lead to a freezing user interface. You could verify my assumption by sleeping for 10 seconds in onPreferenceChange() with the following code.

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object value){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        // do nothing
    }

    return true;
}
```

To my knowledge, there are two options to achieve what you want:

1: You let the preference change temporarly pass (always returning true), independent of its validity.But you trigger the WebServiceCall in onPreferenceChange. You just don't wait for it to finish.
As soon as your WebServiceCall finishes, you revert the users preference change in case it was invalid. You should inform the user about reverting his change. This option makes  sense if you can assume that in most cases, the change will be valid.

2: You build a custom activity allowing the user to change the relevant setting. There you can call your WebService. You should show a ProgressBar while it's running. When your call returns, you know whether the change is valid or not. And only after that, you commit the change to the SharedPreferences.